# Debugging Unobtrusive Validation (client side)

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-validate, unobtrusive-validation

I am using unobtrusive validation. My form is rather complex and on cursory look there's no "visible" validation error.

However when I call:

```
 $(valForm).valid();
```

The result is `false`. I need to debug why, if there's a hidden element etc. that is somehow tripping off a rule. Or may be even the rule itself may not be appropriate.

How can I debug the validation? I need a property/method that tells me which element is bad, and also the rules that it sets off.

I have tried looking into `$.validator` also, but could not find anything that seems related to what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `.validate()` instead of `.valid()` it has a property called `errorList` which contains the offending element and message. The message may be used to track back the rules being broken.